# How to use a JSON file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

First off, I am a newcomer to the Javascript realm. I have a JSON file, such as the following:

```
{"markers": [
  {
   "abbreviation": "SPA",
   "latitude":-13.32,
   "longitude":-89.99,
   "markerImage": "flags/us.png",
   "information": "South Pole",
  },

.... lots more of these in between ....

{
   "abbreviation": "ALE",
   "latitude":-62.5,
   "longitude":82.5,
   "markerImage": "flags/us.png",
   "information": "Alert",
  },
] }
```

I have been doing a lot of research as to how I can bring this file back into my script only to find ways to encode strings into JSON files. Basically, I want to read this file through javascript, something like this... (I know this isn't how you code)

```
object data = filename.json  
document.write(data.markers.abbreviation[1])
```

Can someone please give me clear instruction on how to go about doing this. Remember, I am a newcomer and need specifics since I'm not up to par with the javascript jargon.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First you need a handle on a file. You need to get it somehow either through ajax or through server-side behaviour.

You need to tell use where the file is. How you plan to get it and what serverside code your using.

Once you have you can use `JSON.parse(string)` on it. You can include the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) file if you need to support older browsers.

If you use jQuery you can also try [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) for parsing instead.

An option for remotely getting json would be using [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

To load it you can either use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) or some kind of library with ajax functionality like [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`Ajax.Request`](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax). It can be done in raw javascript but that's just ugly and re-inventing the wheel.

```
$.getJSON("document.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // data is a JavaScript object now. Handle it as such

});
```

Comment: Well, like I said, I just started learning javascript, this is all totally new to me - I'm trying to base if off my experiences with programming in java. Raynos, would you be kind enough to write some example code. Say if you had a JSON file called 'document'. What would you do to read that file back into javascript?

Comment: Are you running a server? Is the file located on a server?

Comment: No, this is just a small project I am doing, its all contained with a directory on my desktop and it will not be published to the internet.

Comment: Raynos, I have a file call grndstats.json which was formatted using java. Now I am using javascript, try to read that file it with no such luck so I can use it to play points on google maps.

Comment: @Stephan are you running the code in the browser? If your not then that's completely different.

Comment: Yes, I am running it in a browser.

Comment: Then if you include `jQuery` in your code and use `$.getJSON` would be the easiest method.

Comment: Raynos, would you be so kinda to write the line of code for it. I have the jQuery.js in the same directory as my browser and json file.

Would it be something like, var data = $.getJSON(grndstats.json);

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out and let you know. I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: @Stephan click on `$.getJSON` follow the url and look at the code samples. What I wrote is very similar. It'll be useful to read and learn the simple things yourself.

Comment: To add a minor point. jQuery has it's own JSON parsing library internally so you don't need both `json2.js` and `jQuery.js`. Just jQuery on it's own is fine.

Comment: When I use jQuery.js, is there something I need to write in my browser for it to be enabled so I can use the code? Or do I just need to have it in the directory only.

Comment: @Stephan `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_url" />`

Comment: in windows phone it is not working .... what is alternate can you please give if any ?