# How to read a text file which contains a Json string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a JSON file in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828207/how-to-use-a-json-file-in-javascript)

I put a JSON string in a text file. 
Now I want to read this file in order to transfer the string to an object using Javascript.

How Can I do to read the file?

Comment: Where is the file? What kind of environment are you in - a web page?

Comment: Have you [searched](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+read+json+file)?

Comment: javascript makes this very complicated php would be a lot easier to do this...

Answer (score 0):

ok you can use the HTML5 file api if you want to do this on the client. Here is some sample code this should get you started.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Untitled Document</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                body 
                {
                    font-size:18pt;
                }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function init() {
                    var bHaveFileAPI = (window.File && window.FileReader);

                    if (!bHaveFileAPI) {
                        alert("This browser doesn't support the File API");
                        return;
                    }

                    document.getElementById("fileElem").addEventListener("change", onFileChanged);
                }

                function onFileChanged(theEvt) {
                    var thefile = theEvt.target.files[0];

                    // check to see if it is text
                    if (thefile.type != "text/plain") {
                        document.getElementById('filecontents').innerHTML = "No text file chosen";
                        return;// this will just get out of the function.
                    }

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    //file reader has an event there is no need to assign an event listener the 
                    //onload event can just be assign like the below.
                    reader.onload = function (evt) {
                        var resultText = evt.target.result;
                        document.getElementById('filecontents').innerHTML = resultText;
                    }
            // readAsText is a native method of the FileReader object.
                    reader.readAsText(thefile);
                }

                window.addEventListener("load", init);
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>Reading File Data as Text</h1>
            <form action="">
            <label>Select a file: </label>
            <input type="file" name="files" id="fileElem" />
            </form>
            <p>File contents: </p>
            <textarea cols="80" rows="10" id="filecontents"></textarea>
            </body>
            </html>
```

this will only work on firefox and chrome since they are the only once supporting the file API otherwise you can an http request if the file is on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Use an `XMLHttpRequest`, aka an AJAX call, to load the file into JavaScript.

Comment: OP never said the file is located on a server.

Comment: True, but it is a likely case - certainly likey enough to guess based on the little information there is. After all, OP never said it *wasn't* on a server.