# Loading object from JSON file into javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How do I load an object into javascript if it is available in a json file?

I have the following script in my html:

```
<script src='scene.json'></script>
<script>
  var x = scene.x;
</script>
```

And this is the file scene.json, located in the same folder:

```
{"scene": {
  "x": 0,
  "y": 0,
  "w": 11000,
  "h": 3500,
}}
```

But the json file is not loaded properly (unexpected token ':') and the scene.x reference is also probably not the way it should be done. Is it possible to refer to the data directly? Or does it need to be loaded by some http request?

Comment: Invalid JSON, remove the last ,

Comment: @Anders it's still invalid javascript though

Comment: The object has a property `scene.x`, but you haven't given the object a name.

Comment: @Esailija Did I say JavaScript?

Comment: @Anders nope, just pointing out :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a JSON file in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828207/how-to-use-a-json-file-in-javascript)

Comment: @Anders: The last ',' is there by mistake (careless pruning of code).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
{"scene": {
  "x": 0,
  "y": 0,
  "w": 11000,
  "h": 3500
}}
```

Is invalid javascript (because it's treated as a block), you probably just want a javascript file:

```
var scene = {
  "x": 0,
  "y": 0,
  "w": 11000,
  "h": 3500
};
```

If you want to keep the file as JSON, you cannot reference it from a script element and have it work while being valid JSON. You would need to use ajax request to fetch the file and parse the JSON.

Comment: Thanks. My intention was indeed to keep the file as JSON, but I will opt for the easy way out instead.

Answer (score 24):

Modify this to javascript:

```
var scene = {
  "x": 0,
  "y": 0,
  "w": 11000,
  "h": 3500
};
```

Or use jQuery api and function [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
<script>
  var scene={};
  $.getJSON('scene.json', function(data) { 
    scene=data;
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

set your json data to one variable like

```
data =  {"scene": {
  "x": 0,
  "y": 0,
  "w": 11000,
  "h": 3500
}
}
```

then access it as

```
data.scene.x //it will give 0
```