# Read Json file data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, file

```
function uploadJsonFunction(){
  var jsonURL = "C:\Users\My Documents\new\WebContent\JsonFiles\TreeJson\countries.json";
}
```

- countries.json is valid json and the above path has countries.json file.
- I want to read the countries.json file whole data/contents using javascript.

Here is my Json:

```
{
  identifier: 'id',
  label: 'name',
  items: [
    {
      id: 'AF',
      name: 'Africa',
      type:'continent'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't even try to file the local file system. Host the file on a webserver and use XHR.

Comment: thats also not valid JSON, you need double quotes and the property names also need quoting, paste what you have into this web site http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 14):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "\countries.json",
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```

For safety reasons, The `C:\Users\My Documents\new\WebContent\JsonFiles\TreeJson\countries.json` url won't work in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to see this example.

[Jquery to get Json](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

-or-

[How to use a JSON file in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4828272)

Hope may help you.

Answer (score -1):

Why not to try Google:
http://www.json.org/js.html

I used this for Android app that worked with PhoneGap(HTML+Javascript+JQuery)

Worked fine.

My Method:

```
var link_name = pathtojson.json

$.getJSON(link_name,
function(data){
var ttext = (data["SearchResponse"]["Translation"]["Results"][0]["TranslatedTerm"]);
document.getElementById('ttexti').innerHTML = ttext;
}
);
```