# JSON Object Retrieval in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>EPA</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
//UV
var text = '{"ZIP_CODE":92507,"UV_INDEX":8,"UV_ALERT":0}'
var obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "UV INDEX" + "<br>" + "Zip code: " + obj.ZIP_CODE + "<br>" + "UV_ INDEX: " + obj.UV_INDEX + "<br>" + "UV_ALERT: " + obj.UV_ALERT + "<br><br>" ; 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

At the moment, I am typing out the JSON object. Is there anyway I can download the JSON object from a URL instead of providing it?

Comment: A typical solution for this sort of thing is AJAX/XHR. There are other solutions, but you can start with that one. Mozilla has a tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Or you just create a JavaScript and put it in it's own script: `var obj = { .... };` and `<script src="myData.js"></script>`.

Comment: This was answered here:
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649829/read-json-file-data-using-javascript>

Comment: *"create a JavaScript object"

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for example:

```
// get json data from a url
var urlString = "/example/getdata";
$.getJSON(urlString, function(obj){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "UV INDEX" + "<br>" + "Zip     code: " + obj.ZIP_CODE + "<br>" + "UV_ INDEX: " + obj.UV_INDEX + "<br>" + "UV_ALERT: " + obj.UV_ALERT + "<br><br>" ; 
});
```

Comment: The return "obj" may be an array. try something like this: obj[0].ZIP_CODE  If that works then loop over the "obj" in a "for" statement and access it that way.