# Loading JSON data from a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

This may be a duplicate of any question but I was not able to find a solution to my problem.

I am building an MVC4 application in which I want to load JSON data from another JavaScript file, using AJAX.

For this, I tried using `$.getJSON()`, `$.ajax()`, `$.get()` other similar functions to load data. It is a simple AJAX call, nothing fancy! Eventually I realized that I need to make this call to a controller/action which would load the JSON and return it back. This solution worked for me.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/controller/action", // <-- How can I refer to the JSON file directly here?
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
    },
    error: function(err) {
    }
});
```

I want to know if there is some other way for me to load this file using JavaScript in the view itself without invoking any controller/action?

> Note: The file is a .json file and not a .js file. I don't want to include the file in any `<script>` tag!

Comment: This post may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828207/how-to-use-a-json-file-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you don't have a mime type of type json specified in your web.config and IIS/IIS Express is returning a 404 error.

Try modifying your web.config like so:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

You will also need to change the dataType to json instead of application/json:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Content/your.json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (err) {
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

To refer a JSON file, you can use the `Url.Content()` method in your `Javascript` :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Content("~/Content/your.json")", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (err) {
    }
});
```

In this case, I have a `your.json` file in `Content` folder.

Hope it helps !

Comment: This method converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path and not used for reading files.